# RoboMongo 0.8.5 Error inserting Date

Tags: mongodb, date, robo3t

Tried many formats like:

```
manufactureDate : new Date("2009-8-2"),
```

or

```
manufactureDate : new Date(2009,8,2),
```

or even

```
manufactureDate : new Date("Feb 8, 2009"),
```

Each validation try ends with:

```
Unable to parse JSON
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `robomongo` when you right clicked on collection name and click `Insert documents...`  new pop up window open and if you insert `dates` as below and click on save button, then it shows error `Unable to parse JSON` because of `robomongo` not understand `new Date()` function in insert document view. This consider as `JSON` and `{manufactureDate : new Date(2009,8,2)}` not a valid `JSON` format. So Instead of inserting `dates` using `Insert documents...` use direct mongo command

[image]

Insert date using query for run this query press ( `ctrl + enter` ) :

[image]

This will insert date in `ISODate` format.